# Cant wrap my brain around towers of hanoi recursion in python

Tags: python, recursion

I understood recursions for factorials and other math cases, but this one is eluding me.

So, we have to break it into n-1 down to the base case, but I don't see how the code is breaking down to output all the steps?!

```
1   def printMove(fr, to):
2       print('move from ' + str(fr) + ' to ' + str(to))
3   
4   def Towers(n, fr, to, spare):
5       if n == 1:
6           printMove(fr, to)
7       else:
8           Towers(n-1, fr, spare, to)
9           Towers(1, fr, to, spare)
10          Towers(n-1, spare, to, fr)
11  Towers(3,'t1','t3','t2')

move from t1 to t3
move from t1 to t2
move from t3 to t2
move from t1 to t3
move from t2 to t1
move from t2 to t3
move from t1 to t3
```

How does this work? Do I need to be able to grok this, or does writing the code at a high level by coding the general idea knowing the details will work out suffice?

Answer (score 2):

Reducing the boilerplate might help with grasping the recursion:

```
def hanoi(n, src, hlp, dst):
    if n > 0:
        hanoi(n-1, src, dst, hlp)
        print("moving disc " + str(n) + " from " + src + " to " + dst)
        hanoi(n-1, hlp, src, dst)
# call with:
hanoi(3, 'src', 'hlp', 'dst')
```

**Explanation:**
The recursion is based on moving the first n-1 discs from the "source" to "helper" (middle tower) - which is done by using the "destination" tower as the "helper". This is done in the line: 
`hanoi(n-1, src, dst, hlp)`

Then move the biggest ring (n) from the "source" to the "destination" (which is done in the "print").

And then again, recursively, move the n-1 rings from the "helper" to the "destination" while using the "source" pole as the "helper": `hanoi(n-1, hlp, src, dst)`

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the details of how code works is necessary for fixing problems with the code when they happen.  It is nice if you code a general algorithm that you were given or found and it happened to work without much trouble.  Struggling through the design and development on your own is much harder.  Not knowing how your code works will prevent you from fixing it.

Comment: Thanks, I hear that. Do you have insight into the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes recursion involves what I like to call a "leap of faith".  Moving a single disk with nothing on top of it from one tower to a destination is easy, you just move it.  So let's *assume* that the recursive function `hanoi` can move a pile of `n` disks from the current location `src` to a specified destination `dst` using a spare tower `hlp` as needed.  Once we make the assumption that it can be done, it's easy to see that what we need to do is move the pile of size `n-1` off the bottom disk and onto the spare tower, trivially move the bottom disk to the destination, and then move the pile of `n-1` disks from the spare tower back onto the bottom disk at the destination.  Mission accomplished!  Alfasin's code rewrite shows this clearly once you realize that calling the `hanoi` function with 0 disks is effectively a no-op, so when there is a single disk it gets moved but the two recursive calls bracketing bracketing that move do nothing.

Comment: Thanks. I'm intrigued by this answer. Can you elaborate on the leap of faith? How do I know that the recursion is able to whittle down the tower? Just by laying out the moves at a high level and hoping it will sort them out?

Comment: The leap of faith aspect isn't hoping things will just work out, it's starting with the premise that the operation **can** be represented functionally. Once I have a function that will move a pile of disks from here to there, I can use that function on a "smaller" problem to yield a solution to my current problem. If a sequence of smaller problems converges to a trivial solution case, you're golden. So assume that `hanoi` can move a pile of disks from here to there. The solution then follows - move a smaller pile off the bottom disk, move that disk, then move the pile back on top.